# Primefaces picklist dualList object become empty

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, picklist

The pickList dualList object become empty when the object loads.

This is the pick list definition

```
<p:pickList id="queuesPickList" 
            value="#{manageApplications.dualListQueuesToBeAddedToTheApplication}" 
            var="queueToAdd" itemLabel="#{queueToAdd}" itemValue="#{queueToAdd}">
</p:pickList>
```

The dualList object being used is composed by two List of Strings

```
private List<String> queuesSouce = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> queuesTarget = new ArrayList<>();
private DualListModel<String> dualListQueuesToBeAddedToTheApplication;
```

The list load properly and I am able to manage object one side another.
[image]

Until this part everything looks good. The source and target objects loads successfully and the pick list is functional. Immediately after creating the dualList I am listing the contents for **source** and **target** and both are there.

There is a button down below to save the changes made by calling an actionListener.

```
<p:commandButton value="SAVE" id="saveQueuesButton" 
                 actionListener="#{manageApplications.saveQueuesToTheApplication()}"
                 oncomplete="PF('dlgAddQueuesToApplication').hide();"
                 update="addQueuesToApplicationPanel">
</p:commandButton>
```

The actionListener for now is just printing the values from the dualList object.

```
public void saveQueuesToTheApplication() {       
            System.out.println(this.dualListQueuesToBeAddedToTheApplication.getTarget());
    }
```

> Now both, .target() and .souce() are empty. There are zero object in
>   there.
>   [image]

Reading the Primefaces documentation it says that the converter is needed to deal with you own type. Since I am using plain vanilla List of Strings that is the native object for the pickList component I didn't bother to build the converter class.

What Am I doing wrong?

best regards,
Neliosam

Answer (score -1):

There was **nothing wrong** with the code. The issue was related with the scope.

The pickList was being used in a **modal dialog window** and somehow this was not reflecting the changes into the dualList component.

I have removed the component from the dialog window and added to a `<h:panelGroup>` that is only rendered when needed using the `rendered=#{booleanCondition}`.

I cannot explain exactly what are the restrictions when using a modal dialog window, but it was preventing the component from updating the variable.

Hope this help someone else facing the same issue!

Comment: So, you had the picklist in a dialog that was inside the form? And now its outside of dialog but still in form?

Comment: Hi Jaquen; The form is unique and I am using template to build the page.
The pickList was initially designed be in a modal dialog window and I found that using dialog window has your restrictions. I have changed the code to put the pick list inside a panel that is rendered only when needed.

Comment: It sounds to me as you don't have a form inside the dialog, and the dialog last in page? That's how to do it

Comment: Correct, there is form inside the dialog. The form came earlier in the template page.

Comment: Then put appendTo="@(body)" on it. I doubt your conclusion that there is something special about picklist making it not work in dialogs

Comment: I will definitely make a try! Thanks for your assistance Jaquen

Comment: I am running into the same problem with a picklist in a dialog form